# Add to iAuditor Response Set (Invalid request payload JSON format)

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, post, urlfetch

Using https://developer.safetyculture.io/?shell#add-a-response

I have the following:

```
function addResponse(){

 var url = 'https://api.safetyculture.io/response_sets/responseset_id/responses';
 var myBody =  {"label": "String To Add"};
 var headers = {"Authorization" : 'Bearer ' + 'api_key'};
 var params = {
   'method': 'POST',
   //'muteHttpExceptions': true,
   'headers': headers,
   'contentType': 'application/json',
   'payload': myBody
 };

UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);

}
```

I am able to get the responseset (https://developer.safetyculture.io/?shell#get-a-global-response-set) so I know the URL, Responseset_ID and key are correct.

```
Bad Request","message":"Invalid request payload JSON format"
```

How should I be correctly formatting `myBody`?

Comment: In that case, please modify `'payload': myBody` to `'payload': JSON.stringify(myBody)` and test it again.

Comment: @Tanaike This works. Thanks. Why?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your additional question, when `'payload': myBody` is used, `label=String+To+Add` is sent as the data. I think that the reason of this value might be due to the specification of Google Apps Script. In this case, the data cannot be parsed at the server side. When `'payload': JSON.stringify(myBody)` is used, `{\"label\":\"String To Add\"}` is sent as the data. By this, the JSON data can be parsed. If this was not the explanation you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: @Tanaike That's great, thanks for the explanation! :D

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue, because I couldn't find the questions using your endpoint with Google Apps Script.